# Different phase in capacitively coupled RLC circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, experimental-physics, electric-circuits

I was trying to work with some data for a lab report I'm writing about capacitively coupled RLC circuits.
The setup is pretty simple and looks like that:
[image: Schematic]

Where $C^{'}$ is the coupling capacitance.

I took some data using an oscilloscope, I was using a very low frequency square wave in order to see the exponentially decaying wave.
Then tried to fit it to the theoretical function using Matlab. 
First I've tried to fit it to $e^{-\gamma t +\varphi_{1}}\cos\left(\pi F_{+}t+\varphi_{1}\right)\cos\left(\pi f_{-}t+\varphi_{1}\right) $ where $F_{+}=f_{+}+f_{-},\ F_{-}=f_{+}-f_{-}$

Because I though that I probably would need to add some constant time-shift.
So I've tried using the same in every place that I had $t$.

That didn't work, but it was quite reasonable because $t$ in the exponent has a $\gamma$ coefficient so I would expect its phase to be different, but that didn't work either.

What did work after trying several permutations of placing the phases in different places was this $e^{-\gamma t + \varphi{1}}\cos\left(\pi F_{+}t+\varphi_{1}\right)\cos\left(\pi f_{-}t+\varphi_{2}\right)$.

But I don't get why would one cosine and the exponent share the same phase while the other is totally different, this is not really part of my lab report but it would be nice to understand why this happens.

The "good" fit:
[image: fit]